# Cant npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, npm-install

Hi im having an issue where i cant install tfjs-node because its fails on node-pre-gyp. There are similar issues that have been raised but i have tried and can't seem to get it working. I have reverted to python 2.7. Here is the error:

```
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Comment: In which OS are you trying to install it on?

Comment: Its on Windows 10.